# How to make Tikz picture not fullpage?

Tags: tikz-styles

No matter how small my image is, it renders in the center of a new page. How to make it "above and below" the text?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start0) [startstop] {Start};
\node (start) [process, below of=start0] {Start};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=start, yshift=-2cm] {Evaluation completed?};
\node (yes) [startstop, below of=dec1, yshift=-2cm] {Evaluation results};
\node (no) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=3cm, yshift=3cm] {Continue};
\draw [arrow] (start0) -- (start);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (yes);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -| node[anchor=west] {no} (no);
\draw [arrow] (no) -| (dec1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption {Evaluation cycle of a long computation}
\label{fig:evaluationCycle}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `figure`  is a _floating_ object. You might be interested in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/82917).

Comment: you may like to show the code which produces the output you describe  -- the above code will not compile without the style of nodes